# Can't access MongoDB from subdomain on same server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx

I am running NginX, Node and Mongodb. And it seems that I can't acces the same database from a second app I am running. For example, I don't get anything back when I do:

```
collection.findOne({
    name: someName
}, function(err, results){
    // Returns no errors or results. Just stops working.
});
```

I can access the database perfectly fine from my first app, but **not** the second one.
This is the code I use to connect to the database in both apps.

```
Server = require('mongodb').Server,
Db = require('mongodb').Db,
db = new Db('database', new Server('localhost', 27017, { auto_reconnect: true }), { w: true });
```

Anyone know what the problem might be?

Edit: Does it have something to do with the subdomain or ports? Too many connections?

Edit 2 (more info):

I run mongodb with `service mongodb start`.

In my `/etc/mongodb.conf` I have `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` and `dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb` (rest is default)

In both my apps I run the same code to establish a connection to the database, but only the first one works (I know that because I am able to retrieve information from the database in my first app).

The apps are running on different ports. The first one is running on port `1337` and the second one runs on `3000`.

Comment: Can you include all information about your configuration?  Including mongod configuration, and how you know that the connection from first app is succeeding and from second app are not succeeding?

Comment: can you check your mongod logs - that's the real way to know if you are actually successfully connecting - it's possible you are not getting any data because you may be querying the wrong DB or the wrong collection?

Comment: I just cleared my logs and checked. When I connect from my first app I get connection logs. But on my second app it just says:

`Sun May  5 23:15:58.342 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017`

I am pretty sure I am querying the correct db/collection (copied over the code and checked multiple times). Could it have something to do with nginx?

Comment: if you don't see a connection accepted message in mongod logs then your connection is not succeeding at all.  You now might want to check what your code is actually getting when it constructs a new Server object - and if there is logging you can enable between your app code and mongod (like ngix) then it may help.  Do you actually restart your mongod for each app?  If you try app1 first and then app2 why would you see "waiting for connections" - that line is only output once per restart of mongod...

Comment: I just restarted mongod for each app while testing, just in case. Well, I don't think the problem has anything to do with mongodb, but rather how I've chosen to configure my set-up. I'll be doing some more  testing and see if I can find something.

Comment: you can always switch app2 to run on port that app1 runs on in case there are some security settings...

Comment: I just tried that as well. Didn't work. I think I might be going crazy.

Comment: Found the error. The mongodb module wasn't installing correctly for some reason with `npm install mongodb` so I just went ahead and copied over the mongodb directory I had to the second app!

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'localhost' as the host name to connect to this server.

This means you will only be able to connect from the same machine that `mongod` is running on with that hostname.

Unless all your apps run on the same server as `mongod` you will need to change your connect code to use the actual hostname of the `mongod` server.

Comment: What do you mean by actual hostname? I disabled `bind_ip` and used my server ip instead of `localhost` and it still doesn't work for my second app that is running on the same server as mongod.

Comment: how did you disable bind_ip?  what exact option is mongod running with?  Where exactly are the two apps running?